# When uploading files in PayPal app creation portal I get error 413 "request entity too large 1"

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using PayPal adaptive payments and I am unable to upload files in PayPal app creation portal. When I submit an application it shows an error `413 the entity is to large`. I am sending just 200 KB file. Please tell me how can I solve this error.

Comment: please show your code, otherwise it's impossible to help. The description is too vague.

Comment: Grammar, structure.